# How can I hide Dialog of ListPreference or prevent opening it in setOnPreferenceClickListener method but not disabling preference of course

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I want to display list of bounded bluetooth devices in `ListPreference`, but Bluetooth may be disabled on a device and I need to enable it first, I call intent for enabling BT on preference click and of course dialog popups of this preference

```
listPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
    if (!btAdapter.isEnabled) {
        val enableAdapter = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
        if (enableAdapter.canBeHandled(context.packageManager)) {
            startActivityForResult(enableAdapter, BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_ENABLE_CODE)
        }
    }
    true
}
```

How can I dismiss this dialog or prevent showing it at some conditions (`!btAdapter.isEnabled`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decided to create custom class:

```
class ListPreferenceActiveControl : ListPreference {

    var isActive = true

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    )

    override fun onClick() {
        if (isActive) {
            super.onClick()
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

`listPreference.isActive = btAdapter.isEnabled`